# Force Restful Authentication to login as a specific user (an admin function)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, restful-authentication

I'm using Restful Authentication and I'd like to be able to log in as different users on our site to investigate issues they may be having ("see what they see"). Since all passwords are encrypted I obviously can't just use their passwords.

So, how can I force a session to be logged in as a specific user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In your `sessions_controller` add action `impersonate` like this:

  ```
  def impersonate
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    logout_killing_session!
    self.current_user = user
    flash[:notice] = t(:logged_in)
    redirect_to root_url
  end
  ```
- Then in your routes extend session resource with the member `impersonate`:

  ```
  map.resource :session, :member => {:impersonate => :post}
  ```
- Finally, somewhere in your admin views add a button to each user called "Impersonate". It will have to look something like this (assuming that user is in local variable `user`):

  ```
  <%= button_to "Impersonate", impersonate_session_path(:id => user.id) %>
  ```

Using this approach you also avoid overriding any tracking data such as time of the last login, etc.

P.S. Don't forget to require admin for `impersonate` action in sessions controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override `session[:user_id]` with the id of the user you want to be.  One easy way is to have the user log in as an admin and then give them a drop-down of usernames.  When they submit the form, have the controller set `session[:user_id]` and then reload `current_user`.  The admin will then 'become' that user.